# How to write a string in a file using vim editor from command line

Tags: vim, append

I want to create a new file using vi editor from command line and add a string to it multiple times say 100. Using `vi -S command.script file.txt` is supposed to do the trick where a new file file.txt will be created and the commands given in command.script file can write to this file. My command.script contains

```
:%100a hello world 
:wq
```

But its's not working, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you interactively execute `:%100a hello world` in a Vim session, you'll get `E488: Trailing characters`. Looking up `:help :a`:

> ```
> :{range}a[ppend][!]   Insert several lines of text below the specified
>                       line.  If the {range} is missing, the text will be
>                       inserted after the current line. [...]
> These two commands will keep on asking for lines, until you type a line
> containing only a ".".
> ```

tells you that the text has to be put in *following lines* (and concluded by a line with only a `.` character).

Or did you mean to use the normal mode `a` command? (That one takes a `[count]` to multiply; your `%100` range is wrong, too!)

You can also use the low-level function `append()`, repeating the string with `repeat()`.

#### summary

```
$append
hello world
[...]
hello world
.

execute "$normal! 100ahello world\<CR>"
" Easier with o instead of a:
$normal! 100ohello world

call append('$', repeat(['hello world'], 100))
```

#### non-Vim alternatives

But honestly, if that is your real use case (and not just a simplified toy example), you don't need Vim at all for this. Here's one example for the **Bash** shell:

```
$ for i in $(seq 100); do echo "hello world" >> file.txt; done
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am doing benchmarking for vim editor that's why cannot use the other solution. I guess I have to use the normal a command.          {a   Append text after the cursor [count] times.  If the
     cursor is in the first column of an empty line Insert
     starts there.  But not when 'virtualedit' is set! }
But I don't know how to give this command in script file.

Comment: I've added a summary of all 3 Vim alternatives; I had used those for testing, but somehow forgot to add them to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ":normal! 100ahello world" in my script file now.